# Child routes not working inside RadSideDrawer (Err: Cannot find primary outlet to load)

Tags: angular, telerik, angular2-routing, nativescript, nativescript-telerik-ui

I want to use `<router-outlet>` inside RadSideDrawer **drawerMain**

but i get the error `Cannot find primary outlet to load Component`

The component has

```
 directives: [NS_ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES]
```

The HTML has `<router-outlet>` Tag
so it should work

Code: https://github.com/telerik/nativescript-ui-samples-angular/issues/13

Notice: when i remove RadSideDrawer codes from HTML file  works normally. So i think the problem is due to  with RadSideDrawer

Any solutions? Thanks

Comment: Please post the code that demonstrates what you try to accomplish.

Comment: sure https://github.com/telerik/nativescript-ui-samples-angular/issues/13

Answer (score 1):

The `<router-outlet>` can not be inside a `<template>` element. It must be added directly to the view.

I assume the template is rendered somehow but it is not obvious from the code you provided where or how that is happening.

Comment: Yeah but how can i make router-outlet works without this template tag:   <template drawerMain> </template>?

Comment: I don't know NS and I don't know `RadSideDrawer` but if you have a route for the component that contains this view, then this component needs to contain a `<router-outlet>`. To me it seems the `<router-outlet>` isn't rendered anywhere. If you wrap the `<router-outlet>` with for example `<div>xxx<router-outlet></router-outlet></div>`, is `xxx` shown on the screen?

Comment: Yes every xxx is working normally, Consoling the button shows that it works normally but nothing is being rendered to the router-outlet

Comment: Sorry, then I don't know. If you can reproduce in a Plunker it would be worth a bug report in the Angular GitHub repo.